# Grammar of Othello, Lines 442-450, Act 3, Scene 3, Othello

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, early-modern-english

> 442 O, that the slave had forty thousand lives!
>   443   One is too poor, too weak for my revenge.
>   444   Now do I see 'tis true. Look here, Iago;
>   445   All my fond love thus do I blow to heaven.  ([This](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/joy-and-pain/201401/what-is-the-difference-between-envy-and-jealousy) motivated this question)
>   446   'Tis gone.
>   447   Arise, black vengeance, from thy hollow cell!
>   448   Yield up, O love, thy crown and hearted throne
>   449   To tyrannous hate! Swell, bosom, with thy fraught,
>   [450](http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/othello/OthelloNotes33.html#442)   For **'tis** of aspics' tongues! [(Source, but I haven't linked all the footnotes here)](http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/othello/T33.html)

1. Would someone please reorder the (hyperbaton) in line 445? I doubt my guess because it sounds positive to mention 'heaven', instead of hell: Thus + do I blow + all my fond love + to heaven?

2. What's the antecedent of the implicit 'it' in 450?

3. Please explain line 450? How can [the answer to #2] [be of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=to+be+of#of__23) venomous snakes' tongues?

Comment: (1) O is *surrendering* all his love (positive feelings) to heaven, to make room for his hate (negative feelings). (2) According to the footnotes in your source, *fraught* was another way to spell *freight*, meaning burden. The antecedent to the implicit *it* is exactly this burden: the dense mass of hate O is cultivating for Cassio. (3) The hate is made of the worst, wickedest, most poisonous substance in the world: snake venom. It's real bad ju-ju.

Comment: *Fraught* is a noun there. Once again, the OED would come to the rescue. +1 to Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Line 445:

> All my fond love thus do I blow to heaven/'Tis gone

could be rephrased as:

> Now I am blowing up/blowing away all of the love I feel, so that it's not here any more.

"Heaven" in this sense is a general reference to the sky, not to the afterlife; the love is dissipated in the atmosphere.

2) "Fraught" is the antecedent of "it." This is not the modern adjective "fraught," but an archaic noun, meaning something like our modern word "freight" or "cargo;" what his bosom is full of. So:

3) Othello is saying that aspics' tongues, standing in for poisonous or venomous feelings, make up the contents of his heart; he is consumed by bitterness and anger.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer #3

*Aspic[s]* is one of the names for the common European viper [(Vipera aspis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_aspis)

*Aspic* (for viper) is perhaps a little old fashioned and the [better known meaning of aspic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspic) is that of a food product that is normally meat encased in a jelly.

Another use of *aspic* is for [lavender oil (oil of aspic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender_oil)

Comment: This doesn't answer the third question, which states the meaning of Aspic as a snake.  It asks how that is appropriate to the antecedent of 'it'.